# ASP.Net MVC3: UrlHelper Extension method requires argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create an extension method. But I get:

> No Overload for method `MRUrl` takes 0 arguments

HtmlHelper.cs:

```
namespace MyNS.Helpers
{
   public class MyHelper
   {
    public static string MRUrl(this UrlHelper url)
    {
         return "blah"
    }
  }
}
```

View:

```
@MyNS.Helpers.MyHelper.MRUrl()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not calling the extension method correctly. It should be:

```
@Url.MRUrl()
```

Please read about how extension methods work in C# before using them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

An extension method extends a given type (`UrlHelper` in your case) and is invoked on an **instance** of this type. So since inside your view you already have an instance of `UrlHelper` (throughout the `Url` property) and so you can directly invoke your extension method on it.

Before being able to invoke an extension method you need to bring it into scope by adding the namespace in which its containing class is defined:

```
@using MyNS.Helpers
@Url.MRUrl()
```

Also extension methods must be declared inside a **static** class. Your C# code won't even compile. So fix it:

```
namespace MyNS.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelper // Bad name choice I know.
    {
        public static string MRUrl(this UrlHelper url)
        {
            return "blah";
        }
    }
}
```

All that's standard C#, nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC or Razor.

Now something ASP.NET MVC specific: if you want to avoid the need of having to bring the namespace into scope into each view (`@using MyNS.Helpers`) you could add it to the `<namespaces>` tag of your `~/Views/web.config` file (not to be confused with the `~/web.config`).

Comment: Excellent answer. People like you make the world go around :)

Comment: @Darin, you are a rock-star in stackoverflow. Thanks for all your great support !